# Is it possible to disable character hiding when typing in your username?

Tags: git, configuration

By default, in command line git, when one tries pushing or pulling they're asked for username and password. When typing those, the characters don't appear which is quite logical for password. However, hiding characters when typing username is just an annoyance to me and I'd like to disable that option. Is it possible? Maybe my google foo is just too weak but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!